# Calling functions vs dispatching events

Tags: actionscript-3, oop, events, design-patterns, observer-pattern

What is the use of creating own events like this when you can just call the function directly.

For example

```
var customEvent:Event = new Event("ev");
_myObject.addEventListener("ev", handler);

private function handler(e:Event):void
{
    //Do something
}

//And then dispatching the event else where like this
_myObject.dispatchEvent(customEvent);
```

When you can simply call the function directly like this

```
handler();
private function handler():void
{
//do something
}
```

What exactly is the point of custom events? In this situation, which one should I use for efficiency and least resource consumption?

Comment: With dispatched events you can have events dispatched from any thread but always run the handler from a single thread. Very common for GUI code where the drawing routines need to run from the GUI event thread. Perhaps the functions called by the handler aren't reentrant.

Comment: You should rather look into Signals than events. Managing a callback function reference can get tedious without events/signals.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In case of dispatching an event the 'dispatcher' doesn't need to know anything about listeners. It is even possible that no listeners exist.

In case of calling a function directly it has to know the name of the function, it has to have a reference to the object implementing the function, and so on. It makes the code harder to re-use.

Answer (score 0):

In terms of efficiency, and in my honest opinion maintainability, you should prefer direct method invocation.

Events are more generic and normally used for [Publish-subscribe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Publish%E2%80%93subscribe_pattern) patterns.  You can create event based systems fairly easily in any language and would involve maintaining a list of subscribers for each event that can be dispatched.  This list must be checked and traversed invoking all subscribers, this normally can be done fairly efficiently with dictionaries or other data structures.

If you stick with a consistent messaging pattern then events can be helpful with abstracting logic from GUI representation.  Many languages use events to integrate with the GUI system including C#, AS3, Objective-C.

In general message systems can become harder to maintain as the project size increases as you lose compile time checking in favor of a more generic dynamic dispatching mechanism.